# Deploying .war application in Tomcat to root

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

My .war application runs on TomCat

I am able to deploy my .war application to a specific directory e.g. www.abc.com/specific

I would do this by renaming my application specific.war and then going to Tomcat Web Application Manager and then going to "WAR file to deploy", select my WAR file and deploy it.

However I would like to deploy it so that if the user types www.abc.com he/she will go straight to the application, without specifying the directory.

How is this possible? Thanks [I have tried calling the application root.war]

Comment: http://benhutchison.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/how-to-configure-tomcat-root-context/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by using forwarding/masking (through the domain name provider)

I **forwarded** www.abc.com to www.abc.com/specific
and I **masked**  so that "specific" is not shown

Comment: how did you mask it?please if you could provide details

Comment: This was a while back (!) but I assume I did it using the following: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name

Answer (score 4):

Two ways:

- name the war file `ROOT.war`
- specify the context `path` attribute in `META-INF/context.xml` - [see here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: Hi. I tried the first way. I named the war file ROOT.war, and deployed as usual.  However I could not find it afterwards in the manager. It was simply not listed.  When I typed in www.abc.com then I was taken to the Application manager...

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure if this answers your question. But I believe u can automatically navigate to the page u want using the

```
<welcome-file></welcome-file>
```

in the web.xml file of ur web app.